# THREE.js - How to fade the background?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to recreate the effect of fading the drawing buffer and leaving trails of the drawn objects, instead of clearing it every frame. It's a pretty simple effect that in 2D would be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/faRW3/1/

```
// draw stuff
c.fillStyle = "red";
c.fillRect(Math.sin( time )*50+70, Math.cos( time )*50+70, 20, 20);

// fade background
c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

But I haven't found the way to do it in WebGL, especially using Three.js. I tried to do it by setting preserveDrawingBuffer to true and playing with the Effect Composer but haven't been successful.

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to place a transparent plane behind the scene and set `preserveDrawingBuffer = true`.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
renderer.autoClearColor = false;

// background plane
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0.1 } ) );
plane.position.z = -10;
scene.add( plane );
```

For a live example see: http://vincemckelvie.com/Potluck/Cartwheel/

three.js r.64

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I thought of the plane but not about placing it behind the scene. I guess the trick is to keep it behind everything when the camera moves.

Comment: Well, you can use an orthographic camera to render the plane first, and then render the scene on top in a second render pass.

Answer (score 0):

The technique described by WestLangley works very well, but if you want more control over your motion trails you can also use `WebGLRenderTarget`.

You might have noticed for example that setting the `opacity` of the plane to values lower than `0.1` results in permanent stains on the screen. With render targets it is possible to fix that.

The technique requires three scenes and three textures:

- sceneContent contains cube
- sceneComp contains quadComp with material (textureNew + textureOld)
- sceneScreen contains quadScreen with material (textureComp)

And they should be rendered like this:

- render sceneContent, cameraPerspective onto textureNew
- render sceneComp, cameraOrto onto textureComp
- render sceneScreen, cameraOrto onto textureOld
- render sceneScreen, cameraOrto onto screen

There is no need to set `autoClear` to false or `preserveDrawingBuffer` to true.

For a live example see: https://codepen.io/brunoimbrizi/pen/MoRJaN